# Find next and previous Record to display in Userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have a `userform` in which I want to display records. However, the code is returning on the first found value:

```
Private Sub commandbutton3_click() 

Dim c As Range
Dim a As String

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("N:N")
Set c = .Find(What:="Pending", LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not c Is Nothing Then
   FirstAddress = c.Address

   Do
      Set c = .findnext(c)
      a = c.Offset(0, -9).Value
      Me.Control1.Value = c.Offset(0, -13)
      Me.Control2.Value = c.Offset(0, -12)
      Me.Control3.Value = c.Offset(0, -9) & " " & c.Offset(0, -8)
      Me.Control4.Value = c.Offset(0, -7)
      Me.Control5.Value = c.Offset(0, -6)
      Me.Control6.Value = Format(c.Offset(0, -10), "dd-mmm-yyyy")
      Me.Control7.Value = c.Offset(0, -5)
      Me.Control8.Value = c.Offset(0, 10)
      Me.Control9.Value = c.Offset(0, -4)
      Me.Control10.Value = c.Offset(0, -3)
      Me.Control11.Value = c.Offset(0, -2)
      Me.Control12.Value = c
      Me.Control13.Value = Format(c.Offset(0, -1), "dd-mmm-yyyy")    
      Me.Control14.Value = c.Offset(0, 1)
      Me.Control15.Value = c.Offset(0, 2)
      Me.Control16.Value = Format(c.Offset(0, 3), "dd-mmm-YYYY")
      Me.Control17.Value = c.Offset(0, 4)
      Me.Control18.Value = c.Offset(0, 6)
      Me.Control19.Value = Format(c.Offset(0, 5), "dd-mmm-yyyy")
      Me.Control20.Value = c.Offset(0, 7)
      Me.Control21.Value = c.Offset(0, 9)
      Me.Control22.Value = Format(c.Offset(0, 8), "dd-mmm-yyyy")

    Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> FirstAddress

End If

End With

End Sub
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You've got these tests at the *end* of your loop:

```
Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> FirstAddress
```

This means that the code keeps finding new values, writing them to the controls (each new one overrides the previous value) and only stops *once* the first value has been found again. You should test to see if `FindNext` has looped back to the first cell before you write values to your controls.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("N:N")
Set c = .Find(What:="Pending", LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not c Is Nothing Then
    FirstAddress = c.Address

    Do
        Set c = .findnext(c)
        If c.Address = FirstAddress Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        a = c.Offset(0, -9).Value
        ' Do the rest of your code here
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing

End If

End With
```